# Copyrighted images

Tags: discussion

What is procedure for copyrighted images? e.g. [This one](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1327/is-bad-posture-bad-for-anything-other-than-your-back). Is it ok to reproduce copyrighted material in an answer, or should it just be linked to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is OK to use *fragments* of copyrighted material under fair use.

http://fairuse.stanford.edu/Copyright_and_Fair_Use_Overview/chapter9/9-b.html

> The four factors judges consider are:
>
> 1. the purpose and character of your use
> 2. the nature of the copyrighted work
> 3. the amount and substantiality of the portion taken, and
> 4. the effect of the use upon the potential market.

Comment: Fragment?  http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a85dd8f2970b-pi

Comment: Indeed! http://www.portmann.com/farside/

Comment: You mean, it *may* be okay to use fragments of copyrighted material. Fair use is a case-by-case analysis. Sometimes, use of full copies of the original work are fair use. Sometimes, use of fragments is not fair use.